# Combinatorial analysis to maximize a value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, tidyr, scenarios

I have the following table:

```
df = structure(list(test_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), person = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor"), points = c(1, 5, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 2, 1)), .Names = c("test_id", "person", "points"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to determine a couple of scenarios and need your help on scenarios 2 & 3:

1. Which single person tallies the most points across all the tests,
   e.g. using dplyr: 
   `df %>% group_by(person) %>% summarize(most_points = sum(points)) %>% top_n(1,most_points)`
2. Which two people combine to tally the most points across all tests (taking the maximum point value between the two people for each test)

   **Expected output**: person a & person b would be the best two person combination, with the sum of their points being 17 (b wins tests 1,2 & 3 and a wins test 4).
3. Which three people combine to tally the most points across all tests (taking the maximum point value between the three people for each test)

   **Expected output**: person a, person b & person c would be the best three person combination, with the sum of their points being 19 (person b wins tests 1 & 2, person d wins test 3, person a wins test 4)

This is a very simplified table and in reality I have hundreds of thousands of rows I'll be analyzing with many more people and test_id's. Note that not everyone has a point value for each test.  I'm not interested in a weighted average, simply **maximum points they (or a combination of two/three of them) have accumulated**.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your expected output for points 2. and 3. ?

Comment: Sorry @Lamia, should have done this from the get go.  2.) Person a & person b would be the best two person combination, with the sum of their points being 17 (b wins tests 1,2 & 3 and a wins test 4).  3.) Person a, person b & person c would be the best three person combination, with the sum of their points being 19 (person b wins tests 1 & 2, person d wins test 3, person a wins test 4).

Comment: In the case of 2 people, b wins tests 1 (with 5 points) and 2 (with 6 points), but d wins test 3 (with 6 points) and a wins test 4 (with 2 points). Therefore shouldn't the best 2 winners combination be "b and d" with 17 points? And in the case of 3 winners "a,b and d" with 19 points?

Comment: In the case of 2 people, there's actually two scenarios that come out to 17.  B wins tests 1 (with 5 points), 2 (with 6 points), and 3 (with 4 points), and A wins test 4 (with 2 points), Or B wins tests 1 (with 5 points) and 2 (with 6 points), and D wins test 3 (with 6 points).

Comment: @Lamia: the optimal combination will not always include the winner of each test. Instead, I'm looking at the optimal combination of 2 and 3 people that will maximize the overall sum of points.

Comment: I think I finally understood what you were asking. I'll edit my answer soon..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to get here, but here's what you could do.
We'll first change the format of the data:

```
library(tidyr)
dfs=spread(df,person,points)
dfs[is.na(dfs)]=0
pers=unique(df$person)
```

This returns:

```
  test_id a b c d
1       1 1 5 2 0
2       2 0 6 5 0
3       3 3 4 5 6
4       4 2 0 1 0
```

Then, we'll look for all the combinations of two people using `combn`, and determine the maximum value between the two for each test, and sum it across all tests. With that we can identify the pairs that have the highest sum:

```
cc2=combn(1:length(pers),2)
values2 = sapply(1:ncol(cc2),function(i) sum(apply(dfs[,cc2[,i]+1],1,function(x) max(x))))
names(values2) = apply(cc2,2,function(x) paste(pers[x],collapse="-"))
values2=values2[values2==max(values2)]
```

This returns:

```
a-b b-c b-d 
 17  17  17
```

For combinations of 3 people, we do the same thing:

```
cc3=combn(1:length(pers),3)
values3 = sapply(1:ncol(cc3),function(i) sum(apply(dfs[,cc3[,i]+1],1,function(x) max(x))))
names(values3) = apply(cc3,2,function(x) paste(pers[x],collapse="-"))
values3=values3[values3==max(values3)]
```

This returns:

```
a-b-d 
   19
```

Comment: Hi @Lamia, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!  Since you've responded, I've had to add another element to the analysis.  I need to rerun these combinations within groups.  Take the example in the below comment, where I've added a "subject" column.  I need the max sums within these groups using the same methodology you've outlined already.

Comment: structure(list(subject = c("math", "math", "science", "history", 
"history", "science", "english", "english", "math", "english", 
"history"), test_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), person = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor"), points = c(1, 5, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L), .Names = c("subject", 
"test_id", "person", "points"))

Comment: If you want to do the same analysis for each subject taken separately, you could create a dataframe per subject and do it. Otherwise, split your dataframe into a list `split(df,df$subject)`, and then adapt the analysis to a list format using `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Top two people

```
df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  summarize(most_points = sum(points)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(most_points)) %>%
  top_n(2, most_points)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  person most_points
  <fctr>       <dbl>
1      b          20
2      c           8
```

Top three people (really four with a tie)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  summarize(most_points = sum(points)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(most_points)) %>%
  top_n(3, most_points)

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  person most_points
  <fctr>       <dbl>
1      b          20
2      c           8
3      a           6
4      d           6
```

Comment: Thanks @manotheshark.  Instead, I'd like to find the optimal combination of people that will yield the highest point total.  E.g. if b & c were in fact the best combination, then there would just be one output value: the sum of the higher point total between b & c for each item. Hope that is more clear.